# Firebase Functions: cold start and idle times

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

We are using Cloud Functions for Firebase as a backend for our JavaScript application. We want to communicate to one of our customers a somewhat deterministic behavior of our API endpoints. Is there any information available on timings regarding cold starts and instance shutdowns?

How long does it take until an idle instance is shut down?

How many users do they need to have during a specified amount of time so that they do not encounter too many cold starts?

Comment: I have changed the question a little bit to be clearer. There is also an upvoted answer. What has to be done to improve this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not published information, and the implementation details may change at any time.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the quick response. I understand that you do not want to publish the current implementation, if you think that this might change. Is there anything I can give our client?

Comment: Only what's in the documentation. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#cold_starts

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson.  But to be honest, with respect, that's a bit nebulous compared to other cloud providers and PAAS providers like AWS and Heroku who both clearly document what their idle time values are.  Is there no way you can give us an idea?  Otherwise, how are we to count on Firebase as a reliable vendor/partner if we can't be sure of the performance characteristics of your platform?

Comment: @Joel Bear in mind that Cloud Functions is still in beta, so there are no guarantees or SLAs.  After beta exit, there may be more information, but currently there is nothing to publish.

Comment: @DougStevenson thanks for the quick response!  :-)  Believe me, I like cloud functions.  It's just that on our devo stage, the cloud functions can be fairly slow when they are idle ... and that always seems to happen when an SVP or other VIP is testing it.  That leads to a chain of questions like "why is the app so slow" to which we have to explain in technical terms "it's not slow, it's just idled and will be faster under load when many users are using it and keeping the functions warm".  But that doesn't go over well with SVPs ... Any advice?  Would a cron job to keep functions warm be bad?

Comment: @DougStevenson BTW, we would be willing to pay $ to keep functions warm and avoid cold starts if that helps ... :-)

Comment: @Jeol Stack Overflow isn't the right place to talk about money for paid support.  You might have better luck in a different support channel.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/support

Comment: @Joel We are using a cron job to keep functions warm and it's ok from our perspective. It might not be the "right" way, but it works.

Comment: You can't really keep functions "warm" under load, because you will still have to pay the cold start cost of the 2nd, 3rd, and Nth servers that could come into existence when load demands it.  Server instances will go away when load decreases.

Comment: But @DougStevenson, if your cron job calls the function say once per minute and the function only takes 50 ms to execute under load, isn't that function able to handle about 1,200 requests per minute under load of which you're only using 1 to keep it warm/alive?  So the other 1,199 "request capacity" slots are still open.  As long as the idle timer on the function is longer than 1 minute and as long as your request load from clients doesn't exceed 1,199/minute, then you shouldn't need a 2nd server or a cold start right?

Comment: @Joel Sure, if all the requests come in one after another, and not bursty at all.  Under bursty load, new server instances will be allocated to handle the demand.

Comment: @DougStevenson I am aware that we are only keeping one instance warm in our setup. With enough traffic, we would not need this. In our setup, however, this is enough to avoid the 8s cold startup time and to keep our <1s average response time that can be easily achieved under load, but not for 100 concurrent requests on a cold process, which will all wait for 8 seconds.